# Insert do nothing and vice versa - 2 tables in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have two tables like as shown below

**Table_1**

```
id  first_name  last_name   email
1   Artemas     Jack        asaggs0@si.edu
2   Caro        John        cstot1@businessinsider.com
3   Maire       Disha       mtilte2@answers.com
4   Cristiano   Herreros    cherreros3@xing.com
5   Mirabelle   Muschette   mmuschette4@discuz.net
```

**Table_2**

```
id  first_name  last_name   email
1   Artemas     Jack123     asaggs0@si.edu
2   Caro        John        cstot1@businessinsider.com
4   Cristiano   Herreros    cherreros3@xing.com
6   Arjun       Master      Arjunmas@gmail.com
```

Few points

1. `Table_2` is recent table (which has updated data)
2. What I would like to do is update Table_1 based on Table_2 but

   1. don't disturb the duplicate rows. Because there are no change (ex: Id = 2,4 in table_1 are present in table_2 as well)
   2. Update the modified rows (ex: Id = 1 in table_1 has an updated last name in table_2. It could be any of the columns. We have to look at the Id column and update it if required)
   3. Don't Remove any rows from table_1 which are not present in table_2 (ex: Id = 3,5 in table_1)

I was trying something like this below but it doesn't help

```
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES (SELECT * FROM table_2) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

But not sure how do I retain records like id = 3 & id = 5 as is

I expect my output to be like as shown below

**Output**

```
id  first_name  last_name   email
1   Artemas     Jack123     asaggs0@si.edu
2   Caro        John        cstot1@businessinsider.com
3   Maire       Disha       mtilte2@answers.com
4   Cristiano   Herreros    cherreros3@xing.com
5   Mirabelle   Muschette   mmuschette4@discuz.net
6   Arjun       Master      Arjunmas@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on conflict do update` and use a WHERE clause to only change the rows where something change

```
INSERT INTO table_1 (id, first_name, last_name, email)
SELECT id, first_name, last_name, email
FROM table_2
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
    set first_name = excluded.first_name,
        last_name = excluded.last_name, 
        email = excluded.email
where (table_1.first_name, table_1.last_name, table_1.email) 
         IS DISTINCT FROM (table_2.first_name, table_2.last_name, table_2.email);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Upvoted. I tried. one quick but small issue

Comment: May I know how do you get alias name as excluded without defining anywhere?

Comment: @TheGreat: it's part of the [insert syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)